# Alpha for Huber penalty in `Fit`

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

For the `Fit` function we can define `NormFunction` with Huber penalty.

```
Fit[data, {1, x}, x, NormFunction -> {"HuberPenalty", \[Alpha]}]
```

What is $\alpha$ here? Is it the Huber loss [threshold $\delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) for standardized dependent variable?

It is very slow for 2000 points? Is this a bug? The wrong algorithm is chosen?

```
ClearAll[x, n, xs, data, lm];
dist = TruncatedDistribution[{0, Infinity}, 
   MixtureDistribution[{1, 2}, {NormalDistribution[0, 1/2], 
     NormalDistribution[2, 1/2]}]];
Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, -1, 5}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> Red]
n = 2000;
data = RandomVariate[dist, n];
dataMean = Mean[data];
xd = RandomReal[{0, 10}, n];
data = Transpose[{xd, data}];
lm = Fit[data, {1, x}, x, NormFunction -> {"HuberPenalty", 0.01}];
Show[ListPlot[data],
 Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ListLinePlot[{{0, dataMean}, {10, dataMean}}]]
```